# Java netbeans How to pass value to jComboBox

Tags: java, jcombobox, netbeans-8

How to pass value from one class to jcombobox in another class

```
Public void getItem (){
try {
         dBconnection...
              while(rs.next){
                  String customers = rs.getString (1);
this.jcombobox1.addItem (customers);
}

}

}
```

From this method to jcombobox in another class. The error is in jcombobox?

Comment: There are many ways to do.

Comment: from where you are calling the getItem()? How this this.jcombobox1 will work?? are you creating combobox for each object?

Comment: getItem lets say is a method i class A which is connected to database and is able to display data in jcombobox class A. I want this data to be passed to class B in another jcombobox also. Thanks for asking, i hope i made it a bit clear now?

Comment: did you have the obj of B in A?@Meli

Comment: Yes i made one obj. @Satya

Comment: So why not you call w.r.t B's obj in A since you are having B's obj in A right. @Meli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already having `B`'s class object in `A` lets say ex `Bclassobj`.

```
Public void getItem (){
try {
       while(rs.next){
         this.jcombobox1.addItem (rs.getString (1));
         Bclassobj.Bclassjcombobox.addItem (rs.getString (1));
     }

    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally this is a poor way of coding, no offense.

You should not mix the code for:

1. Getting the connection to database
2. Executing some `SQL` command and fetching data from `ResultSet`
3. Creating graphics

Simply change your method `Public void getItem ()` to `Public List<String> getCustomers()`. This method's business should be just fetching the data from database, and returning the list of Customer's names as `List<String>`.

Then in your **another** class, simply call this method and set the whole `List<String>` as the model of your `JComboBox`.

See the example below:

```
public class AnotherClass extends JFrame{

    private JComboBox<String> jComboBox;

    public AnotherClass() {
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        //... other components
        DBClass db = new DBClass();
        List<String> customers = db.getCustomers();
        jComboBox = new JComboBox<>(customers.toArray(new String[]{}));
        this.add(jComboBox);
        //... other components
    }
}

class DBClass{

    public List<String> getCustomers (){
        List<String> customers = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
             //dBconnection...
            ResultSet rs = null;// your code for getting ResultSet
            while(rs.next()){
                 String customer = rs.getString (1);
                 customers.add(customer);
            }
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return customers;
    }
}
```

Good Luck.

Comment: STaefi thank you for your advice. It might be poor but is working. My dbase contains small data thats why i went for this way. Instead of creating a new method and repeat same code in other class, i was looking for to inherit somehow?

Comment: It is not a case of Inheritance to use it. You should not inherit some class because you want to see it's member variables out of the box. Changes in your code is so trivial and you can do it in an eye flash. See my edit.